# What is the route the current moves in this circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

What is the route the current takes in this circuit? I can't identify which resistors are in series or in parallel.

This is the circuit:

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: Where is your effort, edit it or this question will be closed

Comment: what do you mean tho?

Comment: Also mention your progress. We can help you conceptually but cannot spoon feed you

Comment: lol. She cant solve it if she doesnt know whats in series and whats parallel. She's not asking people to solve it for her.  She's asking how to set up the problem

Comment: I answered this question cause it seems pretty obvious they're just having a hard time understanding the diagram since most circuit diagrams are linear. I disagree with the condescending comments suggesting they just need to work harder.

Comment: Some people find that re-drawing a circuit diagram helps them to understand it. That diagonal line might be throwing you off for example. If you can find a way to re-draw it, so that all of the connections are the same, but every wire is either horizontal or vertical, it may help you to see something that you haven't seen in the original.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you have a junction, the current will split in parallel. Start with the positive end of the battery (the thicker, shorter, darker bar) and every time the current can split into 2+ paths, it will.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the 4 ohm and 6 ohm resistors in series to make a 10 ohm resistor.

However if you then observe both the ends of that 10 ohm reistor are connected across the same potential,  hence no current flows through that branch and you can effectively remove it.

After that I don't think you would have a problem as it is a simple series parallel question